# Using PHP cURL to send a non key-value pair POST request?

Tags: php, json, http, post, curl

Working with a RESTful API (for Rackspace's API for domain records) and I have encountered something for the first time. That is, sending an request as a JSON file and not the usual key-value paired data.

In my case, I am supposed to send a string in JSON format, WITHOUT a key corresponding to it. All the examples I have encountered with cURL always assumes the request page expects one. Besides, it seems that the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option expects an array (read: key-value pair), anyway.

I am able to set the necessary headers (the Content-Type, and other authentication headers), but I am seriously stuck on putting up the necessary JSON string into the request.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the API Documentation:

```
POST https://dns.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0/1234/domains/2725233/records
Accept: application/json
X-Auth-Token: ea85e6ac-baff-4a6c-bf43-848020ea3812
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 725

{
  "records" : [ {
    "name" : "ftp.example.com",
"type" : "A",
"data" : "192.0.2.8",
"ttl" : 5771
  }, {
"name" : "example.com",
"type" : "A",
"data" : "192.0.2.17",
"ttl" : 86400
  }, {
"name" : "example.com",
"type" : "NS",
"data" : "dns1.stabletransit.com",
"ttl" : 3600
  }, {
"name" : "example.com",
"type" : "NS",
"data" : "dns2.stabletransit.com",
"ttl" : 3600
  }, {
"name" : "example.com",
"priority" : 5,
"type" : "MX",
"data" : "mail.example.com",
"ttl" : 3600
  }, {
"name" : "www.example.com",
"type" : "CNAME",
"comment" : "This is a comment on the CNAME record",
"data" : "example.com",
"ttl" : 5400
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are POSTing a file:

```
$fh = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_INFILE => $fh,
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  //...any other options you might need
));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

If POSTing data (like json) use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

```
$data = '{ "foo": "bar" }';
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
  CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  //...any other options you might need
));
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for taking time in helping. I am yet to try out any of these solutions provided here, but looks like this is something that I have been looking for all along!

Answer (score 0):

JSON format intends to have key:value format. On the other hand HTTP GET/POST protocols also work in key/value format. Parameter name should be specified, so that listener will be able to ready the value by getting it by key.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I used to think to. But looks like this situation is bound to be an eye-opener. Please check the addendum to my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class to do just that... it's basically just a curl wrapper. But I cleaned it up, so it's easy to change headers, request parameters, request body, etc.

Here's some sample code on how to get started:

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.md

```
//prepare the message body
    $record = new \stdClass();
    $record->name = 'ftp.example.com';
    $record->type = 'A';
    $record->data = '192.0.2.8';
    $record->ttl = 5771;

    $message_body = new \stdClass();
    $message_body->records = array(
        $record
    );

    $json_string = json_encode( $message_body );

//send the request and get the response
    $client = new \Altumo\Http\OutgoingHttpRequest( 'https://dns.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0/1234/domains/2725233/records' );
    $client->setRequestMethod( \Altumo\Http\OutgoingHttpRequest::HTTP_METHOD_POST );
    $client->addHeader( 'Accept', 'application/json' );
    $client->addHeader( 'X-Auth-Token', 'ea85e6ac-baff-4a6c-bf43-848020ea3812' );
    $client->addHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    $client->setMessageBody( $json_string );
    $response_string = $client->send();

//do something with the response
    $response = json_decode( $response_string );
    if( $response === false ){
        throw new \Exception( 'Invalid JSON response.' );
    }
    $value = $response->one; //or whatever the response values are
```

Note that the OutgoingHttpRequest methods may throw Exceptions, so you may want to wrap it in a try/catch. I've tried to keep it well documented, but please let me know if I've missed something. I'm also available for questions if something's unclear.

I think Zend built a similar HTTP wrapper, if that's more your style:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks Homer! Would try this out.