# Uploading predefined image to FB album using PHP

Tags: php, facebook, image, post, arrays

I have what I thought was a simple requirement. Through a Facebook App, enable a user to upload a predefined image (from within the app) to their own album.

Uploading an image from the user's machine is straight forward and is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/.

What I need to do is substitute the file input for a predefined image. My first though was to control the POST through the server (PHP), converting the image to a bit array.

```
    $byteArray = file_get_contents("../images/gate-banner.jpg");

    $data = array(
        "message" => "test",
        "source" => $byteArray
    );

    $postdata = http_build_query($data);

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: multipart/form-data',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    print_r(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, $context));
```

But this keeps kick back a 400 Bad Request.

What am I missing? Is there a simpler way to accomplish my goal?

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the Facebook SDK foresaw my problems and implemented a solution!

http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a different HTTP client class. See this post for a similar solution that I've provided...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116708/278976

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looks like I wasted an afternoon over nothing though, the SDK has support built in for exactly my requirement.